# Extracting Tabular Image data and Save it in CSV format using python

Tags: python

Got a Tabular data in an image format (see pic1)

[image: Sample]

The tabular data need to be extracted and saved it in CSV format (same as table)

I have used pytesseract to read the data from an image and it partially worked
code:

```
from PIL import Image
from ast import literal_eval
import pytesseract,csv,re,os
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r'D:\Sample.jpg'),lang="eng")

#print(type(result))
print(result)

with open('D:\people.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    #writer.replace(",", "")
    writer.writerow(result)

string = open('D:\people.csv').read()
new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', string)
open('D:\people.csv', 'w').write(new_str)
```

output:

[image: capture]

The output file is opened in text format and I am not able to get the perfect csv format (i.e. like the table in image).

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: This is a well-known, but yet not generally solved problem from the field of of data mining named Table Detection. I am guessing there will most certainly not be a ready-made solution.

Comment: Oh..ok. While I am trying  to save it directly as csv file, the data is populated as
'R','E','P','O',...and each cell gets each character.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, is there a solution for this?